# How to trigger focus event on element inside controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Here's my template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="contact_email">Email address</label>
  {{
    input
    type="email"
    class="form-control"
    id="contact_email"
    placeholder="user@gmail.com"
    value=emailAddress
    autofocus="autofocus"
  }}
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" disabled={{isSubmitButtonDisabled}} {{action 'saveEmail'}}>Submit</button>
{{#if responseMessage}}
   <div class="alert alert-success">{{responseMessage}}</div>
{{/if}}
```

And this is the controller:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { match, not } from '@ember/object/computed';

export default Controller.extend({
  emailAddress: '',
  responseMessage: '',
  isEmailValid: match('emailAddress', /^.+@.+\..+$/),
  isSubmitButtonDisabled: not('isEmailValid'),
  resetForm() {
    this.set('emailAddress', '');

    // focus email input field
  },
  actions: {
    saveEmail() {
      this.set(
        'responseMessage',
        'We got your email and we’ll get in touch soon'
      );

      this.resetForm();
    }
  }
});
```

Is there any correct way to get a reference to email input field inside controller, so I could get it focused, other than just do `document.querySelector()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the ID that's applied to the input you're wanting to focus on by passing it an ID prop.
If you're in a component, you can concatenate the component's id to the name of the input.

Build the ID in the componentjs and pass that into the input field's ID prop.

```
refocusId: Ember.computed(function(){
    return `${this.get('elementId')}-someValue`; 
})
//HBS
id=refocusId
```

Add an action that takes that new property and focuses on it.

```
refocus(){
  let element = document.getElementById(this.get('refocusId'));
  if (element) {
      element.focus();
  }
}
```

I have a [working example in twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6b2eb026f846c2d8995c108fd5909cbc) that you can see.

I **STRONGLY** recommend generating an ID that you use in your component.  Otherwise, you may accidentally use the same ID twice.

Edit:
Since you're in a controller, you won't have access to elementId like you would in a component.  You actually don't have access to a public property or method that you can use.
So,  as long as you're doing this in the controller of a route, you can use the setupController method + route name in the route file.

```
setupController(controller, model) {
    let refocusId = `${this.get('routeName')}-someValue`;
    controller.set('refocusId', `${this.get('routeName')}-someValue`);
}
```

This can be done without any other changes to the controller.

Comment: To make this approach possible I need to make a component tho. In plain controller `this.get('elementId')` returns `undefined`. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer to show a way to generate the ID from the route.

Comment: Thanks Trenton. That's the case, indeed.